# vb.net Search for Full or partial match in Datagridview from TextBox and select the first match while displaying the full datagrid

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview, textbox, match

I have a customers table that is displayed in a datagridview.  I would like the user to be able to enter the customers full or partial last name and click a buttom that would then find the first customer that met the match in the text box.  As an example: The user types "wil" into the text box and the first record found is for "williams" even though the user is looking for "wilson".  The record would be highlighted(selected) and the user could scroll to look at other records and select "wilson" manually (the manual part I can code).

I have searched for hours on the internet and cannot find this type of code.  Most of it is filtering or searching every cell and returning every value.

I am currently reworking a project I did with an access database and vba several years ago. I had thought vb.net would be very similar but it is not similar enough for me to modify this code.  I'm also going to use a sql database.

The index field is obviously cell(0) and last name is cell(1).

I have found a solution although I did have to modify it.  It will do everything I need except one thing.  If I type the letter "H" and do a search on last name, it finds the first lastname that has an "H" in the last name but in a different position from the first letter.  I need it to go to the first last name that begins with an "H".  I have listed my code below.

Dim srch As String
        Dim irowindex As Integer
        Dim strl As Integer
        srch = txtSearch.Text

```
    dgvCustomers.ClearSelection()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvCustomers.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvCustomers.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If dgvCustomers.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString.ToUpper.Contains(srch.ToUpper) Then
                dgvCustomers.Rows(i).Selected = True
                dgvCustomers.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DimGray
                irowindex = dgvCustomers.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value
                MessageBox.Show(irowindex)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If your DataSource is a DataTable, then use a DataView object.

Comment: [AutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource(v=vs.110).aspx) should help you

Answer (score 2):

try this sir.

```
for each row as datagridviewrow in nameofdatagrid.rows
 if row.cells("Lastname").value = txtbox.text then
   nameofdatagrid.clearselection()
   row.cells("Lastname").selected = true
   exit for
 end if
next
```

I think this is your problem? finding lastname match in the datagrid and select it?
hope this will help you :)

Comment: I had already found a solution which I will post below.  I am having an issue that you can help with as your code looks similar to what I found.  When I type in the text box "H"  it will go to the first row that has "H" anywhere in the last name instead of to the first row that has the "H" as the first letter of the last name.  If you could look my code over and offer a solution, it would be greatly appreciated.   I will have to add it in the the answer.

Comment: I had to add it to the original question.  I guess it is obvious I am new to the site.

Answer (score 0):

Dim srch As String
        Dim irowindex As Integer
        Dim strl As Integer
        srch = txtSearch.Text

```
    dgvCustomers.ClearSelection()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvCustomers.Rows.Count - 1
        If dgvCustomers.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value IsNot Nothing Then
            If dgvCustomers.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString.ToUpper.StartsWith(srch.ToUpper) Then
                dgvCustomers.Rows(i).Selected = True
                dgvCustomers.RowsDefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.DimGray
                irowindex = dgvCustomers.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value
                MessageBox.Show(irowindex)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
```